# MySQL query with PHP not returning expected data

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json

I'm trying to access a MySQL DB with PHP in order to populate a Javascript array, but the array always comes up empty. Before, I had a 'www-data@localhost' access error, but couldn't figure it out and have since rolled back the code. Can anyone share any insight?

JS:

```
var arrayPOIs = [];

function getPoints(){
    $.get('getdata.php', function(data){
        arrayPOIs = data;   
    });
}
```

getdata.php:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "pass", "test");

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo("Connect failed: ") . mysqli_connect_error();
    exit();
}

$query = "SELECT * FROM points";

$result = mysqli_query($query) or die(mysqli_error());

$potential = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

echo json_encode($potential);
```

I was trying to output the contents of the table to an array. In my browser's console it's always showing up empty. Such as:

```
arrayPOIs
""
```

I think I might have some issue with the DB connection query process. Although, I'm quite new to this and I'm lost. Any ideas?

Additionally, how and where can I check what PHP is doing realtime, ie, the error messages?

**EDIT:**

Following up on the comments:

- after adding `"json"` as a third parameter, the `arrayPOIs` var became (in FF's console) `Array [ ]`
- my `getdata.php` page comes out empty (blank) when accessed directly

**EDIT2:**

After Niranjan N Raju's help (+1), it's partially fixed. Bad php syntax on my query call. Now, my object is ill formed. I'm getting:

> {"0":"1","id":"1","1":"poi_teste1","name":"poi_teste1","2":"41.1953","latitude":"41.1953","3":"-8.60134","longitude":"-8.60134"}

But I need something like (JSON):

```
name: poi_teste1,
latitude: 3464357247,
longitude: 247245672
```

for each of the rows in the table, which is something like this:

```
id | name    | latitude | longitude
#1 | string  | float    | float
#2 | string  | float    | float
#3 | string  | float    | float
#4 | string  | float    | float
```

Comment: Hi, add an array count before json_encode to make sure that your array is not empty

Comment: Does it work when adding `json` as a third parameter to your `$.get` function?

Comment: Also, visit the `getdata.php` page from your browser, and tell us what it returns.

Comment: I think you have to change the fetch type now. Can't test it, try `mysqli_fetch_assoc`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have missed connection object in `mysqli_query()`

change like this

```
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$query) or die(mysqli_error());
                       ^      ^
```

**Edit**

If you are getting more that 1 rows,like

```
array(
    0 => id,name,lat and long,
    1 => id,name,lat and long,
    2 => id,name,lat and long,
);
```

For above kind of result, output is correct. To access the values in ajax, use `for() loop`

Also, since you don't want the index, remember to change from

`$potential = mysqli_fetch_array($result);`

to

`$potential = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);`

More at [fetch_assoc](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php).

Comment: this is it...! but unfortunately, I think I have some other problem while encoding the object. I'll add detail in the question above. Can you help out?

Comment: ya sure add it. but the above answer is working. i checked it.

Comment: and also try adding `error_reporting(E_ALL)`. We will get exact error.

Comment: @Joum will you get more than one rows rite?? Then output ll come like that only. You can reduce unwanted values in `select`

Comment: yes, I'll get all the rows without filtering with `WHERE`. But my issue is that I need each row in MySQL to be an object in the JS array, so I can access it with `arrayPOIs[0].name` and similar. This doesn't fit, I think. What do I have to change?

Comment: I think it ll fit in for what you need. wait, let me check.

Comment: @Joum did you see my comment on the question?

Comment: did now! :D working like a charm, thank you both very much!

Comment: @NiranjanNRaju If i may edit the answer to fit my comment, is it ok to you?

Comment: @FirstOne ya sure. do it.

Answer (score 0):

Just for future reference, if it might help someone out: after being vastly helped by @Niranjan N Raju and @FirstOne this worked as I intended:

JS:

```
function getPoints(){
    $.get('getdata.php', function(data){
    //gotta do something with that data! :)
    arrayPOIs = data;   
    }, "json");
}
```

getdata.php:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "pass", "test");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo("Connect failed: ") . mysqli_connect_error();
    exit();
}

$query = "SELECT * FROM points";

$resultArray = array();
$index = 0;

if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {

    /* fetch associative array */
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $resultArray[$index] = $row;
        $index++;
    }

    /* free result set */
    $result->free();
}

echo json_encode($resultArray);
```

Small note (I'll figure it out alone :):

- In the MySQL DB, `latitude` and `longitude` are float-type columns. This solution doesn't account for that as they are coming out as strings. I recon that either in PHP or JS I can `parseFloat` them.

Comment: Can you [mysqli_fetch_all](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php) then? Just change the `resulttype` so it doesn't return the index, just the associative array. It would probably look something like this: `$potential = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);`